# How to display a hidden input value after file upload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
 var $fileVideo = $("<form action='videoupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target_video' onsubmit='return videoClickHandler(this);' class='videouploadform' >" + 
    "Video File: <input name='fileVideo' type='file' class='fileVideo' /></label>" +  
    "<input type='submit' name='submitVideoBtn' class='sbtnvideo' value='Upload' /></label>" + 
     "<p class='listVideo' align='left'></p>" +
    "<iframe class='upload_target_video' name='upload_target_video' src='/' style='width:0px;height:0px;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");
```

Now below I have a jquery code which is triggered when the file has finished uploading.

```
  function htmlEncode(value) { return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); }

      function stopVideoUpload(success, videofilename){

          var result = '';
          videocounter++;

          if (success == 1){
             result = '<span class="videomsg'+videocounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span>';
              $('.listVideo').eq(window.lastUploadVideoIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(videofilename));
          }


          return true;   
    }
```

Below is the code where it uploads the file and then uses javascript to recieve the name of the file and the `id` of the file from the database and it will post it back to the javascript function above to be able to display the information:

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileVideo"]["tmp_name"],
      "VideoFiles/" . $_FILES["fileVideo"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;

    $videosql = "INSERT INTO Video (VideoFile) 
    VALUES (?)";

        if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($videosql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }

    //Assign the variable
$vid = 'VideoFiles/'.$_FILES['fileVideo']['name'];

            //Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
$insert->bind_param("s",$vid);

 $insert->execute();
 $id = $mysqli->insert_id;

        if ($insert->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insert->close();     

        }else{
  echo "Upload was not successful";   
  }


     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     window.top.stopVideoUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>,'<?php echo $id . $_FILES['fileVideo']['name'] ?>');
     </script>
```

So if upload the file `VideoFiles/tulips.png`, then in db it looks like this for example:

Video Table:

```
ImageId  VideoFile
23       VideoFiles/tulips.mp4
```

So in the javascript function above it displays this:

`23ImageFile/tulips.mp4`

What my question is though is that I want the `$id` or as in example above `23` to be displayed as a hidden input value. But my question is how to do this?

**UPDATE:**

```
  function htmlEncode(value) { return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); }

      function stopVideoUpload(success, videofilename, videoID){

          var result = '';
          videocounter++;

          if (success == 1){
             result = '<span class="videomsg'+videocounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span>';
      $('.listVideo').eq(window.lastUploadVideoIndex).append('<input type="hidden" name="vidid" value="videoID" />');
              $('.listVideo').eq(window.lastUploadVideoIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(videofilename));

          }


          return true;   
    }
```

..........

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileVideo"]["tmp_name"],
          "VideoFiles/" . $_FILES["fileVideo"]["name"]);
          $result = 1;

        $videosql = "INSERT INTO Video (VideoFile) 
        VALUES (?)";

            if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($videosql)) {
          // Handle errors with prepare operation here
        }

        //Assign the variable
    $vid = 'VideoFiles/'.$_FILES['fileVideo']['name'];

                //Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
    $insert->bind_param("s",$vid);

     $insert->execute();
     $id = $mysqli->insert_id;

            if ($insert->errno) {
              // Handle query error here
            }

            $insert->close();     

            }else{
      echo "Upload was not successful";   
      }


 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 window.top.stopVideoUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>,'<?php echo $id; ?>','<?php echo $_FILES['fileVideo']['name']; ?>');
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "display" mean here? I guess what you want is to set the value of hidden `<input />` field as `"23"`.
If I'm right, you can just change `stopVideoUpload()` to 3 arguments: `success`, `videofilename`, and `ID` (or other name you want). Then, append `<input type="hidden" name="(name you want)" value="(ID you received)" />` into `$('.listVideo')` or other container you want.

If you have already had an hidden field there, just use jQuery's `val()` function to set the value =)

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Hi, sorry or lateness, you see what I have done is just add this line of code in the jquery `$('.listVideo').eq(window.lastUploadVideoIndex).append('<input type="hidden" name="vidid" value="videoID" />');`but what this does is just output the `$id` which in example is `23` but does not output the video file name in other append I have in my original code `VideoFiles/tulips.mp4`. I have included update of jquery in question.

Comment: Don't forget change the arguments in `window.top.stopVideoUpload()`, too. Put a comma between `$id` and file name, and let their order same as in function `stopVideoUpload()` =)

Comment: Can you look at my update and edit my update code to what you mentioned because with my new update again it only displays `$id` and not file name in string and in hidden input it is displaying `videoID`, not the value of the `$id`

Comment: Do you want to display file name in <span> and set id in hidden <input>? Just change the order of arguments in `stopVideoUpload()` (success, videofilename, videoID => success, videoID, videofilename) because the arguments you send is "ID, file name" order...

Comment: Ah ok, the only issue now is in hidden input (which I changed to text input for test), and it still displays the value `videoID` in the text input and not the id

Comment: That cause by you type "videoID" in value directly. Ummm... I think you have to know how to use variable and operator in JavaScript first. Just Google it =)

Comment: Sorry, I know how to do this, i just wasn't thinking. Thank you it works now :)